# ddslike get two values from diffrentes select

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have little problem with ddslike jquery lib

I have two select box like this:

```
<select id="from">
<option value="1" data-imagesrc="img.png" data-description="USD">Dollar</option>
<option value="2" data-imagesrc="img.png" data-description="EUR">Euro</option>          
</select>

<select id="to">
<option value="1" data-imagesrc="img.png" data-description="USD">Dollar</option>
<option value="2" data-imagesrc="img.png" data-description="EUR">Euro</option>          
</select>
```

Javascript of SELECT BOX (Want just the design from ddslike):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#from_fees').ddslick({
    width: 100,
});

$('#to_fees').ddslick({
    width: 100,
});
});
</script>
```

Here my script that i wanted to fetch value of select's options:

```
  $(function(){
          $("#from").change(function(event){
            //alert("Click event on Select has occurred!");
            $("option:selected", $(this)).each(function(){
                var obj = document.getElementById('from').value;
                alert("selected value"+obj);    

            });
          });
        });
```

But i get no results !

I want get the two value from the two select in the same time.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First, you've got to be consistent with your IDs.  You've got id="from" in the html, but you call .ddslick() on the element with id "from_fees".

If I understand, you'd like to get the values of each whenever either one changes.  How about:

```
<script>
  $('select').change(function(){
    var to = $('#to').val();
    var from = $('#from').val();
    // alert("To: " + to + " and from: " + from + ".");
  });
</script>
```

You don't need to use "this", because you want the value out of both of them.